# Is there a gtld that is officially reserved for nonroutable/private addresses?

Tags: dns

My Verizon Quantum router fires up a dns server automatically that allows all devices in my house to have DNS addresses. That's all nice, but the 'local domain' is .fios-router.home.

The use of .home looks to be to be an accident waiting to happen as the icann oozes towards approving .home as a gTLD. Does the current set of standards offer an option here that cannot collide?

Comment: .local I believe.

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2018, `home.arpa.` is reserved by [RFC 8375](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8375).

The other standard option is to register an actual domain, e.g. Verizon could register `fios-home.net.` and configure it on all their routers. Microsoft has already done so with `mshome.net.` in their Internet Connection Sharing feature. People do also purchase their own.

That said, `home.` should be fine for now; while it was planned to be a .gTLD, it's used so widely in LANs that it has been reserved, at least temporarily. `internal.` is also unlikely to ever be a gTLD. (Do not confuse with the `int.` TLD.)

Do not use `local.`, as it is reserved for mDNS ("multicast DNS", i.e. Avahi/Bonjour).

Comment: [Have some further reading](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-use-domain-names-that-you-own.html) if you want it.